# Singleton Fragments and memory efficiency

Tags: android, android-fragments

To reference `Fragment`, there are several ways:

1. Make `Fragment` a singleton
2. Store reference to `Fragment` as a private member in `Activity`
3. Get reference to Fragment using `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` methods of `FragmentManager`

Which way is the best in respect of memory efficiency? Is usage of Singleton pattern discouraged in this case?

Comment: Why do you need your Fragment as singleton? And second - have you heard about setRetaingInstance() fragment method?

Comment: Yes, I know about setRetainInstance(). It's not that I need my fragment to be a singleton, I did this to be able to retrieve reference to the object without storing it anywhere or using `FragmentManager`. Just Fragment.getInstance(), it just couldn't be any easier.

Comment: So you should rethink your idea. Fragment should more or less take care of view. If you want to do some other stuff (sth that should be handled not in UI thread) you can use setRetainInstance...but if you want to keep object across classes you should create normal singleton class or maybe keep it in application context.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm open to new ideas :) I'm new to fragments API, so I'm just trying to find the best way to perform interaction between fragments in different cases.

Comment: Ok, so you want to pass information between fragments...The best way is your solution 3. (If this fragment doesn't exists you can set information in activity which keeps both fragments - but this is only optional).